# Sqlite3 and pthread, double free or corruption (out)

Tags: c++, linux, sqlite, pthreads

I try to create a thread which connect to a database, takes some data from there and print to the console. The problem is that when that thread finish throw an exception:

**double free or corruption (out)**
**Aborted (core dumped)**

I try to use sqlite3 and pthread and this two are not really friends.

I think, but I am not sure that the problems comes from the Database class.

Anyone have any idea what produce the exception?
Here is my code: [link](https://pastecode.xyz/view/1f08167e#Ho0RyuftpdiMJPTiDW0Ghhm87UXcbx3Z)

Database class:

```
class Database {
private:
  sqlite3 *db;
  static int CallBack(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
  {
    int index = 0;
    char** dataToReturn = new char*[1000];

    while (dataToReturn[index])
    {
        index++;
    }

    for (int i = index; i < argc + index; i++)
    {
        dataToReturn[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * sizeof(argv[i - index]));
        strcpy((dataToReturn)[i], argv[i - index]);
    }

    return 0;
}

public:
  char **Select()
  {
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;

    rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);

    if (rc)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
    }
    char **data;

    int rc2 = sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT * FROM SHARED_FILE", CallBack, data, &zErrMsg);

    if (rc2 != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        exit(2);
    }

    sqlite3_close(db);
    return data;
}
```

Thread functions:

```
static void FunctioForThread()
{
    printf("start");

    auto database = new Database();
    char** returnData = database->Select();

    printf("something from db: %s \n", returnData[0]);
    printf("stop");
}

static void *threadd(void *arg)
{
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    fflush(stdout);

    FunctioForThread();
}
```

And the main function:

```
int main()
{
    pthread_t thread;
    char arg[100] = "test";
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &threadd, arg);

    while(1);
}
```

Comment: @user10605163 The requirements are to use pthread. :(

Comment: The exception can be throw because I use malloc in a class?

Answer (score 1):

You are dereferencing `data` passed to `CallBack` in `((char **)data)[index]`, but its value was passed from `data` in `Select` through the callback of `sqlite3_exec`. `data` in `Select` was allocated for in:

```
char **data = (char **)malloc(0);
```

You are not allowed to dereference a pointer to a zero-length allocation. Also note that the behavior of a zero-size `malloc` is implementation-defined, so it should be avoided (as should `malloc` in C++ in preference of `new` anyway).

---

After edit:

Now `data` is returned from `Select` without ever writing to it, but is then dereferenced in

```
returnData[0]
```

in `FunctioForThread`. That is undefined behaior.

Furthermore `sizeof(argv[i - index])` does not return the length of the string that `argv[i - index]` points to. It will return the size of the pointer type. Probably your allocations will therefore be too small, again undefined behavior. Use `std::strlen` to get the length of a zero-terminated string.

Then the pointer `argv[i - index]` may also be `NULL` to indicate a `NULL` value in the returned row (see [documentation of `sqlite3_exec`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html)). In that case `strcpy`ing from it will also be undefined behavior.

The loop `while (dataToReturn[index])` will cause undefined behavior because an array for `dataToReturn` was allocated, but its elements never set.
Even if the values were set, note that the condition is satisfied if and only if the C-style string `dataToReturn[index]` points to has length zero. If such a string doesn't exist in the allocated range, again the behavior is undefined.

---

You also have memory leaks because you never `free` any of your `malloc`ed data and because `dataToReturn` is discarded at the end of each CallBack call, it is not very useful.

---

There is no good reason to use all these C-style constructs. Use `new` instead of `malloc`, `std::string` and `std::vector` instead of `char` arrays, `std::cout` and `std::cerr` instead of `printf` and `fprintf(stcerr, ...`, `std::thread` instead of `pthreads`. The only point were these things need to be considered is at the interface boundary to the C library.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't verify that your answer is correct or incorrect since the relevant information resides on an external website.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I figure out how to use the editor, now every relevant information should be in the post.

Comment: @T.Stefan That's good, but you fixed the error I mentioned in that code for the most part. Please don't do that. Now you are dereferencing an invalid pointer in `returnData[0]` in `FunctioForThread`.

Comment: @user10605163 Thanks a lot for your help, I will try to apply yours tips.